# Object-Relational Mapping to Json instead of a Database

Tags: java, json, hibernate, orm, database-normalization

I have 3 classes:

```
class Employee{ 
  int id;
  String lastName;
  String firstName;
  Department department; //an employee has 1 department
}

class Department{
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Employee> employees;
}

class AllData{
   List<Employee> employees;
   List<Department> departments;
}
```

What I would like is to marshall the AllData class out to json, but unlike a regular marshalling tool such as Jackson, I'd like the data to be normalized and easily 
editable, like such:

```
{
       "employees":[
         {id: 101, "lastName":"Smith", "firstName": "John", "departmentId": 201},
         {id: 102, "lastName":"Jones", "firstName": "Jill", "departmentId": 201},
       ]
       "departments":[
        {"id": 201, "name":"accounting"},
        {"id": 202, "name":"sales"},
       ]
 }
```

Notice that the json is written out without data being repeated.  For example, only the departmentId is written out in Employee, and not the entire Department
object.  And Department does not write out the employees object, because that would be repetitive.  This allows a user to quickly edit the json, which is great for testing where we quickly want to be able to view and modify objects.  We've got all these scenarios with different employees and departments, and if we could edit and view them easily in text, it'd be great for testing.  In a sense, what we want is an object-relational mapping tool like Hibernate, but instead of going from an object to a database, I want to go from an object to an editable text-format (json is preferred).   In theory, Hiberate gives us this when it writes out SQL statements, but SQL is much worse than json for viewing and editing.  If I'm approaching this problem wrong, please let me know.